# ¿Como serializar un dato tipo fecha, con retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

Buen dia.

Tengo un formulario en Android en el cual en uno de los campos selecciono una fecha, este dato lo envío por el método `POST`, para ello estoy usando `retrofit`, pero esta fecha debo serializarla o convertirla a este formato:

> yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss

.

El método `Post` esta así:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/books/{bid}/books")
Call<Book> postBook(@Path("bid") String bookId,
@Field("bookRequest[additionalComment]") 
String additionalComment,
@Field("bookRequest[contactPhone]") String contactPhone, 
@Field("bookRequest[suggestedDate]") String date);
```

¿Como podría solucionar esta situación?.
De antemano gracias.

Comment: podrías dar un ejemplo de tu json

Answer (score 0):

No tiene nada que ver con Retrofit, pero puedes usar esto:

```
public static String getCurrentISODate() {
    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'", Locale.getDefault()); // La "Z" indica UTC, sin offset de zona
    df.setTimeZone(tz);
    return df.format(new Date());
}
```